# Handler functions for an objects with complex names

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JS, so my question may be dumb.

I've got some HTML:

```html
<div class="bigouterblock">
  <div class="inner-block">
...some content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Each class has a proper css style.

I'd like to make a handling for **onmouseenter** event for my inner div.
When I want to do this for some other div, I can make something like this in separate .js-file:

```js
bigouterblock.onmouseenter = function(e) 
{
  console.log("My mouse is in outer block"); 
};
```

But how do I do this for block named ***"inner-block"***? JavaScript handles **"-"** **sign** in the name as minus, and it's reasonable. *But I really wants to preserve that name :)*

What should I do with such a strange thing?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Suggest you start by studying some tutorials about how to query and reference elements in the dom. `bigouterblock` is undefined and code shown will throw errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can query an element like this `bigouterblock.onmouseenter` if `bigouterblock` is its id, not class. If you want to query by class, you should use `document.getElementsByClassName("inner-block")` which returns all elements with the given class name.

```js
for (let inner of document.getElementsByClassName("inner-block")) {
  inner.onmouseover = () => console.log("Over .inner-block");
}
```

```html
<div class="bigouterblock">
  outer content
  <div class="inner-block">
    ...some content here...
  </div>
  outer content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it, if you only have one div with the class inner-block could be:

```
// selects the div element use an unique class name
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("inner-block")[0];
// adds the event listener mouse enter
element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e){
  console.log("My mouse has entered the element"); 
});
```

I would recommend using an id instead of a class selector if you just want to add the mouseenter functionality to only one div or iterating through all elements and adding to each the event listener.